# Expand a specific node of an Angular Material Tree

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using Angular Material Tree and I need to expand, upon certain logic, certain nodes.

I have created an example starting from one of the examples present in the official Angular Material documentation.

At launch, the page looks like this
[image]

If i click the button **Expand Fruits Node** I would like to get to the following rendering

[image]

The code that manages the click of the button is the following

```
expandNode() {
    this.nestedNodeMap.forEach((node) => {
      if (node.item === "Fruits") {
        this.treeControl.expand(node);
      }
    });
  }
```

Unfortunately, if I click the button, nothing happens. Any suggestion on how to reach the desired behavior?

The example code [can be tried here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eirjgm?file=app%2Ftree-checklist-example.ts).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue is that you don't expand the parent.

The tree control only expands the given node, or the descendants of a node (to expand them all at once).

This means you have to find the parent, then expand it, then expand its child.

[Here is the working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eirjgm-dqhb6v?file=app/tree-checklist-example.ts) and the related code :

```
  if (node.item === 'Groceries') {
    console.log('parent found');
    this.treeControl.expand(node);
  }
  if (node.item === "Fruits") {
    console.log('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>found', node);
    this.treeControl.expand(node);
  }
```